How can I smooth out or turn a pixelic mesh into a curve?
I have this mesh in Blender 4.1 and possibly more types of meshes with this type of pixelic art, but I can't figure out how I can smooth it out and turn it into a curve object.


Don't worry about the square faces inside, this is just the initial mesh which I put a Limited Dissolve to remove all the interior vertices so we are left with the edge outline.

I tried Subdivision modifier to no avail

I also tried the Smooth Corrective modifier, but I can't find the right settings to make it smooth. It gets too thin if I set repeat to 20-30. The Smooth Laplacian didn't do anything.

How do I smooth it out and turn it into Curve object? Perhaps I need to use geometry nodes?

You can try a CtrlV > Smooth Vertices in Edit mode, increase the Repeat value:

Also press X > Limited Dissolve to simplify the mesh:

Convert to curve then convert from Poly to Bezier Curve:

Then press V > Automatic to round the vertices:

Result, you can still tweak the vertices so that it sticks more to the shape you want, if it's too different from what you wanted, I guess the solution is to redo the shape from scratch with a curve, taking the original image as reference:


thank you so much!

oh yeah i see notice it doesn't work perfectly, the eye of the dog breaks. this will be a problem since I want to automate this so I can't go in and do manual fixes.

Yes you can still correct in Edit mode afterwards

yes but unfortunately I need to automate this with python later so I can't do manual adjustments. But maybe it is just a setting in the "Limited Dissolve" that can prevent the weird edge generation.

Sure, try a lower angle value when you dissolve

ah i found a way, i just remove all the faces inside so im left with the outline and then do the smoothing. thank you!
